# How to make confusion matrix in YOLOv4 using mAP's output?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, confusion-matrix, yolov4

We have found the mean average precisions. In the map, there are TP, FP, FN values but not TN. So, we are trying to find the TN values from which we can measure our confusion matrix. How can we measure the confusion matrix from the already measured mAP's output?

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. I have TP and FP for each class but no TN and FN. Have you figured out how to solve this yet?